# Why aren't English "flame" and Croatian "plam" considered related?

Tags: etymology

Why aren't Croatian "plam" (meaning "flame") and English "flame" considered to be related, or at least possibly related? They mean exactly the same, and they seem to fit phonologically. Croatian 'p' regularly corresponds to English 'f' by the Grimm's Law. So, why is the English word being a borrowing from Latin "flamma" and Croatian word being related to "pepeo" (ash) considered a more likely explanation?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

English *flame* isn't a native English word, but a loan from Old French *flame*; Grimm's law doesn't apply, as it had long ceased to operate at that point. The initial *f* actually reflects PIE **bʰ*, which would yield *b* in both Slavic and Germanic but became *f* in Latin.

Both English and Serbo-Croatian do have native descendants of the PIE root **bʰel-* that yielded *flame*: English *bale[fire]* (now archaic), Croatian *bijȇl* 'white'. The similarity between *plȃm* and *flame*, however, is just a coincidence.

Comment: How do we know "flame" is not a native English word dating back to Proto-Indo-European?

Comment: @FlatAssembler The word doesn't show up in Old English at all, and is only attested from the 14th century on, at a time when Middle English was in the middle of appropriating a massive amount of vocabulary from Old French in the centuries after the Norman invasion. It also doesn't exist in other Germanic languages except Dutch (which also had close contacts with French) and German (which borrowed it from Dutch; there we have the additional point that if it had been native it would have been *Flahm* by comparison with English and Dutch, but instead it's *Flamme*).

Comment: Great answer! I have a doubt though: PIE *bʰ, according to all the stages of Grimm's law, should yield an f, correct? (bʰ > b > p > f). So, why did english have "bale" instead of something like "fale"?

Comment: @Qwertuy That's how the chain shift is usually represented, but it's only applied once: PIE *\*bʰ* changed to *\*b*, but it didn't then keep shifting after that. Likewise, PIE *\*b* became *\*p* (e.g. *\*h₂ébōl* > *\*aplaz* 'apple') but didn't then keep moving into *\*f*. Proto-Germanic wasn't all voiceless fricatives.